# python pip install mod_wsgi fails with possible unicode error

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to host a web app with Flask. I have a VPS running CentOS. I have Apache 2.2.26 installed.

When I run `pip install mod_wsgi` either in a virtual environment OR on my main Python installation, I get the following errors

This first error is printed before the Python trace...

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home5/arguably/python27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a(abstra     ct.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when maki     ng a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/home5/arguably/python27/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a: could not read sym     bols: Bad value

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

that error is looking at my main Python installation. That's not where the virtualenv is located

The Python error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arguably/webapps/ers_2/ers2venv/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/arguably/webapps/ers_2/ers2venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__     init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/arguably/webapps/ers_2/ers2venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/ba     secommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

That one IS looking at my virtualenv

The lines from the file in the Python trace `text = '\n'.join(complete_log)` ..

```
if store_log:
            log_file_fn = options.log_file
            text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
            try:
                log_file_fp = open_logfile(log_file_fn, 'w')
            except IOError:
                temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
                log_file_fn = temp.name
                log_file_fp = open_logfile(log_file_fn, 'w')
```

Answer (score 5):

Your Python installation has not been installed with a shared library. This is required for mod_wsgi. See the mod_wsgi documentation.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Mixing_32_Bit_And_64_Bit_Packages

Reinstall your Python from scratch and this time use `--enable-shared` to the `configure` script for Python when building it.

Comment: is that possible to do with a virtual environment? Or does the shared library attribute belong to the main installation?

Comment: It is dictated by how the main Python installation the virtual environment was created from was configured at the time of installation. If the main Python installation you use was self compiled from source code, it will not default to installing a shared library, you must configure it to do so.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I'm facing the same issue.Is there any way that I can install mod_wsgi by not reinstalling after uninstalling the existing python? (like making changes to some file or so?)

Comment: Are you asking if you can somehow fix this without rebuilding Python to have a shared library? No you can't. For a discussion on what is needed to properly build Python read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html Ignore that it mentions Docker, all still relevant.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I installed python from the installer and did not encounter any place where I use --enable-shared. How can I reinstall python so that I can enable shared library?

Comment: @Siraj What installer are you talking about? Binary installers are usually always using shared libraries and they clearly tell you if they are 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: I used https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/ Windows x86-64 MSI installer. And when I was installing **mod_wsgi**, I encountered error `Failed building wheel for mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py clean for mod-wsgi
Failed to build mod-wsgi`.

Comment: There should have been a bunch of errors before that. Create a new questions showing exactly what commands you ran and include all the errors. You shouldn't use comments of existing questions for a new problem of your own.

Comment: Ok, Sir. I'm already fed up, I've been doing this for 3 days, I haven't started my development just because of this. I'm blocked here because of some previous bad questions so I'm opening the issue on GitHub,

Comment: If you have been trying to do it recently, the issue may be because builds of mod_wsgi 4.6.2 are broken on Windows. Use ``pip install mod_wsgi==4.5.24``. The issue was only raised yesterday. A fix has already been done today, but not release yet. The symptom will be an error about an undefined symbol ``wsgi_daemon_process``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have raised a new issue on GitHub. 
I tried `pip install mod_wsgi==4.5.24` also right now. Again the same error. I have given the complete output on the issue on GitHub.